# PHP Windows CLI and a "realtime statistics gui"

Tags: php, user-interface, windows-7

I'm attempting to make a sort of realtime display for a project of mine which runs as a PHP CLI application, and I'm having some difficulty clearing the console and making that happen.

Essentially, my end goal is something like this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
|                                          [ _ ] [ [] ] [ X ] |
---------------------------------------------------------------
| Lag: 120 ms              Foo: 1240 bar     Users: 240,000   |
| Some stat: 12434 things  Status: connected Cake: nominal    |
|                 -------------------------                   |
| Some form of console output here, buffered so I can clear   |
| the screen with no worries and it will display nicely to    |
| the end user. A couple of lines of stats, and this output   |
| buffer will suffice, no need for any interactivity. Keeping |
| the positions of the stats and output static increase       |
| readability since I can just check at a glance, and keep my |
| output constantly refreshing instead of every few seconds.  |
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

which would update flicker-free and not cause the actual command line buffer to scroll or increase the number of lines in the buffer beyond the vertical height.

I tested `\r` on a small bit of text, and it could indeed overwrite it in a flicker-free manner. However if that bit of text was greater than one line (which I believe is 80 characters, correct me if I am wrong), then it didn't overwrite the whole line, even if that line was broken by the size of the window rather than by `\n` or `\n\r`. And so, I discarded that approach.

I next turned to [Ansi Escape Codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) and [ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses), only to realize that no, they do not in fact apply to command prompt on Windows 7, as applied by PHP.

How can I achieve the desired effect in Windows 7, without utilizing an alternate command prompt or installing any plugins?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're searching for the wrong solution. You could look into calling the Win32 API with PHP, but I suggest you just run the PHP daemon through MSYS and use ANSI escape codes. That should do exactly what you want.